# IdentityServer and CertificateValidation ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API. For Authentication I'm using right now IdentyServer4. Now I got the additional requirement to apply Mutual TLS. When applying this this results in the following code in my Startup.cs (using: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation (3.0.1) and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate (3.1.3)):

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "<baseaddress>";
    options.ApiName = "<API>";
});

services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCertificate(options =>
{
...
}
```

Now I'm facing the issue that my ClaimsPrincipal is overwritten by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate. This is not desired because we use the claims from IdentityServer4 for allowing/denying functionality.

What's recommended in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are the problem in your code

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

You are overriding the default authentication scheme to certificate.

You should just add your certificate authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "<baseaddress>";
    options.ApiName = "<API>";
})
.AddCertificate(options =>
{
...
}
```

And use this code to authenticate with certificate

```
httpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```